# IOS does not show filled PDF form filled text in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, pdf

Here is what I am doing currently,
My application can fill in the PDF forms with values in the respective fields and generate a new copy of a PDF. Alright, it works fine and get the expected results as I wish.
But my questions are,
When I want to view the generated PDF files with data filled in, it shows nothing in my IPAD.

[image: Here is the end result of my filled form which I grab from the container of my IPAD]

[image: Here is what it display in my IPAD]

I grab the generated PDF files from IPAD container and it's able to show the text in the respective fields in MacBook but fail to display in IOS.
Here is my Objective-C code:

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[self getDocumentsFolder] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"geForm1.pdf"];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:txtFilePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
CGFloat  height  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
CGFloat  width  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

I wonder where is the mistake I had made which cause the filled data not shown in IOS.

**UPDATE:**

I tried open the pdf files in iBook and it do not have any values inside the respective fields. The document is blank. Then I tried open the pdf files in Adobe Reader and thank god all the text is shown in respective fields.

Now my questions, how to make those filled text shown on default/native pdf viewer or web view?

Comment: at first check 'txtFilePath' path contains 'geForm1.pdf' file

Comment: yup, it consist of the correct files. Else nothing will appear.

Comment: would you give the log of "txtFilePath" and "pdfData"?

Comment: in my case "NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"pdf"];" I get result showing pdf

Comment: where if you pdf file locate?

Comment: see my pdf file locates http://imgur.com/IcggPxV

Comment: txtFilePath NSPathStore2 * @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/063768AF-C369-49D1-A288-8DA653D6D993/Documents/geForm1.pdf" 0x00000001703aae20

Comment: pdfData NSConcreteData * 3421606 bytes 0x0000000170075980

Comment: targetURL NSURL * @"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/063768AF-C369-49D1-A288-8DA653D6D993/Documents/geForm1.pdf" 0x00000001742ab220

Comment: I got no issue on reading pdf files. But my issue is the pdf file shown is not fill in with data or text in respective fields.

Comment: The iOS PDF engine doesn't support forms, at least not as of this time (iOS 9). You can implement these yourself (forms are a subtype if Widget annotations - it's a lot of work but can be done; writing is even harder), or you look into existing (commercial) solutions. We are working on one for the last 4 years now over at pspdfkit.com and are trusted by apps like Dropbox or Evernote, which also decided that Apple's built-in engine is not powerful enough and chose us.

Answer (score -1):

It works for my case.

```
-(void)readPDFFile{
//    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
//    NSString *txtFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"geForm1.pdf"];
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"geForm1" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSLog(@"txtFilePath:%@",txtFilePath);

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:txtFilePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
CGFloat  height  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
CGFloat  width  = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

}

Note: I read pdf file from application's bundle folder